# Why GEF Editor Part doesn't show up?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

I followed every step of [this tutorial](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ip/resources/GEF/GEF_Tutorial_2up.pdf) until I had to run the application for the first time, but the Graphical Editor Part doesn't show up. The only difference between the tutorial and my project is that on the Extensions tab of the plugins.xml file, the `org.eclipse.ui.editor` extension doesn't contain a "MyGraphicalEditor (editor)" named child.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you have a project or are you doing the tutorial for training. If it is for the second reason I can point you out some tutorials that I already try and they are working fine!

Comment: It's just for practice, any (better) tutorial would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the reason. Every editor should be added to org.eclipse.ui.editor extension point.

Answer (score 1):

These tutorials will give you more practice and better understanding:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTDraw2DExample.htm

http://nyssen.blogspot.com/2010/12/draw2d-examples-hidden-treasure.html